# Can an XSLT 2.0 function return arbitrary types?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to write an XSLT 2.0 function that returns a result of a specific type--let's say one or more  elements. Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

```
  <xsl:function name="util:find-parents2" as="element(parent)*">
    <xsl:variable name="output" as="element(parent)*">
      <xsl:for-each select="('one','two')">
        <parent>
          <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </parent>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$output"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

Here's the error I get from the Saxon processor:

```
Error at xsl:function on line 192 column 65 of file:/e:/mlsh/recursive.xsl:
  XTTE0780: Required item type of result of function util:find-parents2() is element(parent,
  xs:anyType); supplied value has item type text() Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

But I expected to get something like this:

```
<parent>one</parent>
<parent>two</parent>
```

What am I missing here? I thought I had specified the appropriate type for $output (one or more `<parent>` elements), but the processor clearly isn't getting the message and is seeing only text. How can I return a list of `<parent>` elements here? Thanks in advance...

UPDATE:

Summarizing, the answer to the question in the title is 'yes'. The key in the original example is the difference between `<xsl:value-of>` and `<xsl:sequence>`. Replacing the former with the latter is one way to get the desired behavior. Another way would be to 'unwrap' the contents from the `<xsl:variable>` element, which makes things a bit tidier:

```
  <xsl:function name="util:find-parents2" as="element(parent)*">
    <xsl:for-each select="('one','two')">
      <parent>
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
      </parent>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>
```

Thanks to Michael and Jim for catching my original oversight...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you should remove the final `<xsl:value-of...>`.  `value-of` produces a text node, which is not what you want.  The sequence constructor already contains the nodes you want output.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I often get in the habit of using xsl:value-of, which usually produces the type I want (a text node). But as you noted, xsl:value-of always gives a text representation, whereas xsl:sequence produces arbitrary types.

Comment: Actually, without the xsl:value-of the function would contain only an xsl:variable, so it would produce an empty result. But the answer is broadly right: xsl:value-of is something of a misnomer, because it reduces everything to a text node. Think xsl:sequence.